# What am I doing wrong in my css code? Div is overlapping when it shouldn't

Tags: css

Can somebody tell me why my H2 div is overlapping the float:right div on this page?

http://wreckedexotics.com/test3.html

I tried clear:both - that didn't work
I tried making the H2 an inline with width 100%, that didn't work

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

As always, your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You must establish a new [block formatting context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting) for `<h2>` (and maybe others).
So

```
h2 { overflow:auto; }
```

will work!

Block formatting context allows container to encompass floating children elements too ^^